# Transmitting image file over bluetooth from iphone?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

please, help me.
In my application i need to give user the ability to transmit an image to another phone.

Maybe you can give me some docs or tutorials that'll help me?

Answer (score 0):

Another iOS device or another phone? If is to another phone you can't.

Comment: and if i want to transmit it to ios device?